# MVC vs ASP.net -- Test cases to proof that one is easier to test over the other

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, testing

We are currently in a progress of switching from Asp.net to asp.net mvc framework and I was hoping to find some answers relating to asp.net MVC vs plain ASP.net testing.

There is some in house talk about MVC being more "test friendly", well yes, but in what kind of sense? I mean, can you provide an example to me of a unit test / test case or a scenario where unit testing with MVC would be easier (or preferably much easier) than doing the same thing in Asp.net?

Because we are currently having huge fights over this fact and the two arguments in this conversation are:
1. MVC is more test friendly and easier to test
2. ASP.net can be tested as much as MVC (MVC is built on top of asp.net)

This discussion is going nowhere and I'm hoping to turn to you, all knowing gods of stackoverflow, for help in this matter to decide this. Like I said, I would prefer some examples / cases which I could easily put together on both ASP.net and MVC to prove that MVC is in fact easier to test. Or is it even easier to test? We are attempting to make our development life cycle a lot more test friendlier and this is one of the driving goals for mvc but some old developers insist that asp.net is the way to go.

Can you please provide me with some insight on the matter, personal opinions, objective opinions and all that if possible. And obviously, even better if a test example that I can implement on both frameworks to prove that one is better over the other when it comes to testing.

Thank you!

Comment: If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here.

Comment: don't be like that, it's not. I'm already part of the discussion. But I'm hoping to find some real answers in the testing scenarios since I don't personally have the MVC knowledge to create a test case that would actually prove that it's more test friendly.

Comment: MVC is part of asp.net - that's why it's called ASP.NET MVC. You will be switching from WebForms to MVC

Answer (score 4):

If you construct a WebForms project using the MVP pattern, then it becomes just as testable as MVC.

The difference is, with the MVC framework, it almost forces you to write testable code by default, whereas with WebForms you have to be very disciplined and strict to make it testable. However, there are MVP frameworks available that can help with this, e.g. http://webformsmvp.com/.

Comment: Views aren't intended to be testable, they are supposed to be so dumb that they don't need testing. In MVC you test the Controller class, and in MVP you test the Presenter class. It's the same principle. The only difference is that Controllers and Presenters have a different set of responsibilities in the app.

Comment: Yes exactly.I found this useful [article](http://www.typemock.com/blog/2012/05/22/automated-testing-of-asp-net-mvc-applications/).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used asp.net, so my comment only is about unit testing for asp.net mvc.

In general, (and as Christian wrote) if you're disciplined and strict and using good practices (inversion of control, programming to an interface) code is easy to unit test. If you don't (by e.g. writing directly to the DB from the controller) then even asp.net mvc will be difficult to unit test. Although asp.net mvc tries to force the programmer to separate concerns.

In asp.net mvc the view cannot be unit tested. For this reason the view should be kept simple, only display data from the viewmodel and contain only simple logic (for loops and simple if statements). Again it's up to the programmer to ensure that the view remains simple (using e.g. partial views, extension methods).

The controller and model classes can be unit tested as along as they are not coupled to (dependent on) classes difficult to test (e.g. database repository) or classes that cannot be mocked.

The routing in asp.net mvc can also be unit tested.

Perhaps go through an asp.net mvc tutorial. You should see that many of the classes are loosely coupled and easy to unit tests.

- [mvc music store tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store)
- [nerd dinner tutorial](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Intro.htm) (part 12 has the unit tests)

Answer (score 0):

I've written a Navigation framework for ASP.NET that lets you write unit-testable Web Forms, http://navigation.codeplex.com/

I've implemented the NerdDinner sample for Web Forms using the framework to show it is just as unit test-friendly as MVC, http://navigationnerddinner.codeplex.com/